# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests' error with tkdesigner

Tags: tkinter, path, request, figma

trying to use tkinter designer and when i run this

```
cd Tkinter-Designer
cd gui
python3 gui.py
```

i get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Brodie\Tkinter-Designer\gui\gui.py", line 12, in <module>
    from tkdesigner.designer import Designer
  File "C:\Users\Brodie\Tkinter-Designer\tkdesigner\designer.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tkdesigner.figma.endpoints as endpoints
  File "C:\Users\Brodie\Tkinter-Designer\tkdesigner\figma\endpoints.py", line 3, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Brodie\Tkinter-Designer\gui\gui.py", line 14, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError("Couldn't add tkdesigner to the PATH.")
RuntimeError: Couldn't add tkdesigner to the PATH.
```

i have pip installed requests and pip3 installed requests and no difference

Comment: Try `python3 -m pip install requests`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run using

```
python gui.py
```

Which worked for me

Answer (score 0):

**If you still want to go with using `python3`:**

The error message is indicating that the `requests` module is not found. The `requests` module is a third-party module for sending HTTP requests in Python.

One possible explanation is that the `requests` module simply isn't installed, despite efforts to do so with `pip` and `pip3`. Alternatively, the current environment may not be utilizing the proper version of Python or `pip`, and thus the `requests` module remains inaccessible.

Try activating the virtual environment in which the requests module was originally installed, make sure that your environment is compatible with the necessary version of Python and `pip`. In the case that neither of these options prove successful, consider installing the requests module directly through the terminal with this command:

```
pip install requests
```